# primes and binomial coefficients

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, terminology, binomial-coefficients, math-history

Lets us denote by $\mathbb{P}$ the set of prime numbers.

It is well known that, given an integer $p>1$ :

$$\boxed{p\in\mathbb{P}\Leftrightarrow\forall k\in\{1,\cdots,p-1\},\,p\mid\binom pk}$$

I have three questions :

1°) Does anyone know if this property has an official name ? Or by whom it has been discovered ?

2°) I do know that the implication $\Rightarrow$ can be used to provide a proof of the little Fermat theorem (by induction). Does anyone know of some other significative application of it ?

3°) The implication $\Leftarrow$ is certainly a very bad primality test ! But I guess that it could nevertheless have interesting applications. Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Comment: Concerning 3. Which applications do you expect from this (as you correctly call it very bad) primality test ? I do not think that this sufficient criterion has even a purely theoretical interesting consequence.

Comment: @Peter Frankly, I don't know what to expect. Maybe the proof that positive integers having some special property are in fact primes.

Comment: This is pretty close to and I think mentioned in the AKS paper, or "PRIMES is in P".    They use this fact or a similar one that involves binomial coefficients, but they improve upon the way of using it so that it's no longer a bad primality test, but polynomially efficient!

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU 1. It is a long way from the binomials to this test 2. Polynomial need not mean efficient in practice 3. In fact, the AKS test is not efficient in practice , there are much more efficient tests known (Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely (APR) and Elliptic curve primality proving (ECPP))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem), which more generally computes ${m \choose n} \bmod p$, and it is also a special case of [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), which more generally computes the largest power of $p$ that divides ${m \choose n}$. I don't know if this special case itself has a name.

(Or rather, $\Rightarrow$ straightforwardly follows from these results, and $\Leftarrow$ does too but maybe less straightforwardly.)

Probably the most famous application of $\Rightarrow$ is to prove that the [Frobenius map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism) $x \mapsto x^p$ is a ring homomorphism in [characteristic $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)). I'm not aware of any applications of $\Leftarrow$ off the top of my head.